# Creating an ApplicationDbContext Object

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, dbcontext

When I try to use base("DefaultConnection") I get an error that it "cannot convert from 'string' to 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions'"

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{
}
```

Can I remove the base? I tried but then it gave me an error when I tried to access my database, it gave me an error about my constructor.

Comment: It should be public ApplicaionDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)          : base(options)     { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing in wrong way, it must be declared like this.

```
public ApplicaionDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

And please make sure you register the ApplicationDbContext like the below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    ...
}
```